# Why should this be a while statement and not an if statement?

Tags: loops, if-statement, while-loop, statements

Did a test for class.. and they provided a sample test. One of the questions gave the following code which **calculates the average of the items in a list** , they then asked us to find all the errors:

```
# brightness levels –maximum is 100
shape_brightness = [15,92,38,42] 
item_no = 0
total = 0
if (item_no < len(shape_brightness):
  total = shape_brightness[item_no]
  item_no = item_no + 1
  average = total / item_no
print(“The average brightness level is “+str(averge))
```

However, in the solution they said the biggest error was that it should actually be a **while statement** .. and i dont understand why? Any explanation as to why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all elements to calculate the average. The if statement only visits the first element in this array.

When your code accesses `shape_brightness[item_no]`, `item_no` is the index, so as it is 0, `shape_brightness[item_no]` is just the number 15. In order to include all the other values of `shape_brightness` in your average calculation, you want to access them as well, so to do that you increase your index `item_no` as many times as the number of elements you want to access by using a loop.

A while loop would be one way of iterating over all elements, and changing the 'if' to 'while' would be the fastest correction to this code, but a for loop, with additional changes, would also work. E.g.

```
for item in range(len(shape_brightness)):
    execute
```

in which case the item_no counter becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

Because you need to iterate an array. That tranlates: you need some form of looping!

And if statement does not have that *repetitive* part required here!

Comment: Oh that makes a bit more sense, but i thought we just need to calculate the average once? What exactly are we trying to loop??

Comment: You need to some on ALL elements in the array! How do you do that without reading them all in a loop?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `while` loop because for calculating the sum and number of values for average. You need to repetitively add the values of shape brightness until you have added all the values. Currently, you are using an `if` block which is considering only first value of `shape_brightness` array. You need to put

```
    total = shape_brightness[item_no]
 item_no = item_no + 1
```

inside `while` loop

```
while(item_no < len(shape_brightness))
```